# C# Add items from listbox to Usercontrol

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I am a new programmer. I will try to explain as well as I can. I am programming a tool in WPF. I made a usercontrol as follows.

[User control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkBki.png)

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="30"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="150"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="50"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="30"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Button x:Name="DelOutConBT" Margin="5" Content="X" Click=" Delete ConnSet"></Button>
    <Label x:Name="OutConLB" Grid.Column="1" ></Label>
    <ComboBox x:Name="InConComB" Grid.Column="2"></ComboBox>
    <TextBox x:Name="ConnValueTX" Grid.Column="3" Margin="5"></TextBox>
    <Button Grid.Column="4" Margin="5" Content=">>"></Button>
</Grid>
```

In the mainwindow, I already programmed a listbox and a tab. The listbox will be filled some items with running a Python script.

Now, I want to enable user to add a usercontrol by select a item in the listbox and click button in the mainwindow.

My question is how can the usercontrol load information automatically when it is added. I want the Label in the Usercontrol shows the item selected from the listbox, and the Combobox shows all items in the Listbox.

Then, by clicking the button">>" in the usercontrol, the data in the usercontrol can be saved to a class or sth else. Because I will use all data filled in usercontrols with another Python script.

This is what I programed to add the user control to main window.

Mainwindow.xaml.cs

```
private void ConSel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (ListB.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        string name = ((ListBoxItem)ListB.SelectedItem).Name;                
        ConnSet CSobj = new ConnSet();
        StkConn.Children.Add(CSobj);                
    }                        
}
```

Comment: You should be doing this with a TemplateSelector in an ItemsControl. It would be relatively easy that way.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is a "style" for a listview. Your question isn't very clear, so I can't give you exactly what you're looking for, but here's an example of a ListView using bindings that would do what you need:

**UI:**

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" >
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="150"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Button x:Name="DelOutConBT" Margin="5" Content="X" Click=" Delete ConnSet"/>
                <Label x:Name="OutConLB" Grid.Column="1" ></Label>
                <ComboBox x:Name="InConComB" Grid.Column="2"></ComboBox>
                <TextBox x:Name="ConnValueTX" Grid.Column="3" Margin="5"></TextBox>
                <Button Grid.Column="4" Margin="5" Content=">>"></Button>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
public ObservableCollection<ConnSet> Items { get; set; }

private void ConSel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (ListB.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        string name = ((ListBoxItem)ListB.SelectedItem).Name;                
        ConnSet CSobj = new ConnSet();
        Items.Add(CSobj); // with the correct bindings, this will push to the UI for you
    }                        
}
```

Quick Edit: What's happening in the xaml code is that it's saying "for each item, follow this template for the design" so when a new item is added, it looks at that template and lays everything out for you.

Note that I would recommend looking into MVVM or MVC patterns if you're using WPF. From what I've seen, that's how WPF was designed to be used. There are many good books on the topic that you can check out. Hope this helped!

Comment: First, Thank you for your help. I try to explain more clearly. I do not want the usercontrol added in the listbox. I want to add it in a tab. The listbox and the tab in the mainwindow are already done. My problem is how the Combobox of the UI will load all items from the list box and the Label load the item selected from the listbox. Hopefully, it is more clear. >.<

Comment: I think I understand you a bit better.. I think what you want to do is put a "StackPanel" inside the second tab with a name and then place the control inside that.
     <TabItem>
         <StackPanel x:Name="ControlHost"/>
    </TabItem>

Then:
ControlHost.Children.Add(CSobj);

Comment: If that answers your question, could you please mark it as "answered" and I can add the second comment to my answer so that others can get the benefit of the solution?